# Reshaping/Pivoting Data with Date Value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I need to pivot/reshape long form data 2 ways:
1) adding date columns(End-of_month) and filling in numeric value (total)
2) adding date columns(End-of_month) and filling in date value(day-of-month that reached the 'total' value in previous pivot)

I can do 1 with:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['1-12-2016', '1-23-2016', '2-23-2016', '2-1-2016', '3-4-2016'],
        'EOM': ['1-31-2016', '1-31-2016', '2-28-2016', '2-28-2016', '3-31-2016'],
        'country':['uk', 'usa', 'fr','fr','uk'],
        'tr_code': [10, 21, 20, 10,12],
        'TOTAL': [435, 367,891,1234,231]
        })

data['EOM'] = pd.to_datetime(data['EOM'])
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])


data_total = data.pivot_table(values='TOTAL', index=['country','tr_code'], columns='EOM')

Out[73]: 
EOM              2016-01-31  2016-02-28  2016-03-31
country tr_code                                    
fr      10              NaN      1234.0         NaN
        20              NaN       891.0         NaN
uk      10            435.0         NaN         NaN
        12              NaN         NaN       231.0
usa     21            367.0         NaN         NaN
```

However, trying to change value argument with 'date' produces:
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

I basically want two df's - the one I accomplished, and another in the same format , but instead of the 'TOTAL' value the 'date' in which that total was accomplished.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should be careful, the default aggregation function of `pivot_table` is mean, so you're going to be calculating an average, not totals, when you have more than one measurement per bin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### `set_index` with `unstack`

This assumes the combinations of `['country', 'tr_code', 'EOM']` are unique and will break if they are not.  This is why an aggregation function is important.  We need a rule if and when we get multiple observations of a combination.

```
data.set_index(['country', 'tr_code', 'EOM']).date.unstack()

EOM             2016-01-31 2016-02-28 2016-03-31
country tr_code                                 
fr      10             NaT 2016-02-01        NaT
        20             NaT 2016-02-23        NaT
uk      10      2016-01-12        NaT        NaT
        12             NaT        NaT 2016-03-04
usa     21      2016-01-23        NaT        NaT
```

---

#### `aggfunc` / `pivot_table`

The default aggregation function is `mean` and that makes no sense for dates.  `first` will do.  Could also have used `last` which ALollz had used in their deleted answer.

```
data.pivot_table(
    values='date', index=['country', 'tr_code'], columns='EOM', aggfunc='first')

EOM             2016-01-31 2016-02-28 2016-03-31
country tr_code                                 
fr      10             NaT 2016-02-01        NaT
        20             NaT 2016-02-23        NaT
uk      10      2016-01-12        NaT        NaT
        12             NaT        NaT 2016-03-04
usa     21      2016-01-23        NaT        NaT
```

---

#### `groupby`

Less glamorous way of doing the same thing as `pivot_table`

```
data.groupby(['country', 'tr_code', 'EOM']).date.first().unstack()

EOM             2016-01-31 2016-02-28 2016-03-31
country tr_code                                 
fr      10             NaT 2016-02-01        NaT
        20             NaT 2016-02-23        NaT
uk      10      2016-01-12        NaT        NaT
        12             NaT        NaT 2016-03-04
usa     21      2016-01-23        NaT        NaT
```